# Removing only one group with oracle regexp_replace

Tags: regex, oracle, regexp-replace

I have a string 'hello big world,' and I want to remove 'big world' so that the end result string would be just 'hello,'. I didn't know that It would be that hard. The closest I got was:

```
declare
 l_string varchar2(40);
 begin
    l_string := 'hello big world,';
    dbms_output.put_line(l_string);
    l_string := regexp_replace(l_string, 'hello (.*),$', '\1');
    dbms_output.put_line(l_string); -- it returns 'big world' and that's the part I want to remove 
 end;
 /
```

Answer (score 1):

It returns *big world* because that's what your code says. The last parameter in the `regexp_replace` function is the replacement string. If you want to remove *big world* then search for it and use an empty string as your replacement, i.e.

```
regexp_replace(l_string, 'big world', '')
```

Comment: Oh but I forgot to mention that sometimes it might be 'big earth' or 'big sun'. Only the word big newer changes.

Comment: It doesn't matter what you search for, in order to remove the searched-for string, the replacement string must be the empty string.

Comment: What if the string will be 'hello big world, hello big earth, hello big sun,'? Can I use regexp_replace in that situation?

Comment: Of-course. You need a regex that will find all occurrences of what you want removed, but still the replacement string needs to be the empty string. The question is what do you want to remove from _hello big world, hello big earth, hello big sun_?

Comment: 'hello big world, hello big earth, hello big sun,' ==> 'hello, hello, hello,'

Comment: The problem I have is that I will not know if it will be 'sun' or 'world' or 'earth'

Comment: `hello .*,` is the regex to search for and `hello,` is the replacement.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
l_string := regexp_replace(l_string, 'hello [^,]*,', 'hello,');
```

Your code has 2 problems:

- First in `pattern`, you use `$`, means that oracle only search for the match right before end of string, so for string `hello big world, hello big earth, hello big sun` oracle will never match the part `hello big world,` or `hello big earth,`
- Second is that in `replace_string` you use backreference `\1` while you mark reference in the part you want to remove - `(.*)` in stead of the part you want to keep - `hello`. If you want to use backreference then it should be `regexp_replace(l_string, '(hello) [^,]*,', '\1,');`

Refer to docs [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm)

Comment: Your code will remove everything after `hello` except `,`. For following string it will have the same result. `regexp_replace('hello big test world,', 'hello [^,]*,', 'hello,')`

Comment: @Deep yes, and I think that's what OP want, as in his other comment `'hello big world, hello big earth, hello big sun,' ==> 'hello, hello, hello,' `